# How to compare two Datetime field in Django

Tags: django

I have used `datetime.datetime.now()` for storing `datefield` in my model which is saved as `2016-06-27 15:21:17.248951+05:30`. Now I want to compare the `datefield` with the `datetime` value getting from the frontend, like `Thu May 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (IST)`. How should Django query the model to compare both datefields?

```
# models.py

datefield = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

I have tried converting `datefield` getting from frontend by using `split()` and `remove()` function of Python to create it in format as `2016-06-27 13:25:35`.

But still no solution and getting `Null` even I am comparing same date value like this (2016-06-27 13:25:35) value with this (2016-06-27 12:36:34.898593+00) value, as date in both values are same.

I have checked it using simple Django query as follows:

```
company_details.objects.filter(datefield=datefield).only('par1','par2',...)
```

Comment: You want to compare with the date and time ? or only date ?

Comment: I need comparison for date only

Comment: Note that `datetime.datetime.now()` is a non-timezone-aware time, and the one you are getting from the frontend has a timezone. Conceptually, you can't compare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have converted the date from the front end into a ISO format like `2016-06-27 13:25:35`, you can use it to query the model with one of these

```
Model.objects.filter(date_created__startswith=today)
Model.objects.filter(date_created__contains=today)
```

It works too if you are only looking to filter for a certain date like `2016-06-27`.

```
Model.objects.filter(date_created__startswith=date(2016, 6, 27))
```

---

To parse the date string you are getting from the frontend, there are two options.

If your date string is well-formatted, you can simply parse it with for example `datestring.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` to get a `datetime()` object.

If your date string is *unreliable* and may be formatted in different ways that you can't predict, I would recommend to using [DateUtil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It comes with a parser that will try to convert any string into a datetime, for example

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("Today is January 1, 2047 at 8:21:00AM", fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
(datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 8, 21), (u'Today is ', u' ', u'at '))
```

Comment: Hey my datefield  is not in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S this format,so I am unable to use  strftime,  also I am unable to use parse to convert it into required format . But whatever the query you have given is working fine, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Compare the date and time like this. Just give the variable like this `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` as much you want.

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime
In [2]: past = datetime.now()
In [3]: present = datetime.now()
In [4]: present.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') == past.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[17]: False
In [5]: present.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') == past.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
Out[2]: True
```

If you want to compare only the `date` use like this.

```
if present.date() == past.date():
    #Do your stuff
```

Comment: I don't have both the dates in same format . I need query which will compare both datefield and filter all the data in database on the basis of filtered datetime field.

Comment: Then convert in to a single format like `datetime` then compare with them. How can you compare the data's in different format ?

Comment: Obviously I can't , can you tell me how to convert this (Thu May 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (IST)) in this(2016-06-27 12:36:34.898593+00) format ?

Comment: Wat is the type of `(Thu May 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (IST))` ? `datetime` ?