# Notification when a certain point in time is exceeded (Python)

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I would like to create a To-Do list in which I can schedule date and time of each task. My goal is to get some sort of response whenever the supplied `datetime` is equal to the current time. For example I scheduled *Do laundry* for Monday at 6pm on a Saturday evening. Two days later (on Monday at 6pm) I would like to get a notification that I should *Do laundry*.

Notice that the key idea can be found in the *index() function* in **views.py** in the first rows including the if-statement.

Here is my code:
**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.details, name="details"),
    path("add/", views.add, name="add"),
    path("delete/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.delete, name="delete"),
    path("edit/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("update/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.update, name="update")
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Aufgabenzettel(models.Model):
    Aufgabeselbst = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    Datum = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Geplant = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Aufgabeselbst}"
```

**views.py** (the important part can be found in the index function in the first rows including the if-statement)

```
from django.db.models.fields import DateTimeField
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

from .models import Aufgabenzettel

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    Aufgaben_items = Aufgabenzettel.objects.all().order_by("-Geplant") #arrange objects in the correct order
    for Aufgabenzettel.Geplant in Aufgaben_items: #run through the loop and...
        if Aufgabenzettel.Geplant == now: #...search for items in the database where the scheduled time ("Geplant") is equal to the current time
            return render (request, "aufgabenzettel/add.html") #response in any way e.g. by returning the add.html 
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/index.html", {
        "Aufgabenliste":Aufgabenzettel.objects.all(), #currently not used
        "Aufgaben_items":Aufgaben_items
    })

def details(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    creationDate = aufgabenzettel.Datum
    dueDate = aufgabenzettel.Geplant
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/details.html", {
        "details":aufgabenzettel,
        "creationDate": creationDate,
        "dueDate":dueDate
    })

def add(request):
    addDatum = timezone.now()
    if request.method == "POST":
        Aufgabe = request.POST["Hinzufügen"]
        geplantes_datum = request.POST["DatumFeld"]
        Aufgabenzettel.objects.create(Aufgabeselbst=Aufgabe , Datum=addDatum, Geplant=geplantes_datum) #Aufgabenname und Aufgabendatum erstellen
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/add.html")

def delete(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    aufgabenzettel.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

def edit(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/edit.html", {
        "details":aufgabenzettel
    })

def update(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Aufgabe = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
        Aufgabe.Aufgabeselbst = request.POST["Bearbeiten"]
        Aufgabe.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/edit.html")
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<h1 id="MeineAufgaben">Meine Aufgaben</h1>
    <table>
        {% for Aufgabeselbst in Aufgaben_items %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="{% url 'details' Aufgabeselbst.id %}"> 
                        {{ Aufgabeselbst }}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{% url 'delete' Aufgabeselbst.id %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit"  id="löschenbtn">Löschen</button>
                </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{% url 'edit' Aufgabeselbst.id %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" value="{{ details }}" class="bearbeitenbtn">Bearbeiten</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <h2>
        <a href="{% url 'add' %}" id="neuebtn">Neue Aufgabe erstellen</a>
    </h2>
{% endblock %}
```

**add.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Füge eine neue Aufgabe hinzu!</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'add' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="Hinzufügen" placeholder="Neue Aufgabe">
        <input type="datetime-local" name="DatumFeld">
        <button type="submit" id="Hinzufügen">Hinzufügen</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**details.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ details }}</h1>
    <h3>Erstellt: {{ creationDate }}</h3>
    <h2>Geplant: {{ dueDate }}</h2>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Zurück zu Aufgabe</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**edit.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Bearbeite deine Aufgabe "{{ details }}"</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'update' details.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="Bearbeiten" value="{{details}}">
        <button type="submit" class="bearbeitenbtn">Bearbeiten</button>
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Zurück zu Aufgabe</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**layout.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Aufgabenzettel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>

</html>
```

I don't get an Error or anything but the code is not running as expected. I just want the index function to loop through each element in the database *Aufgabenzettel* in **models.py** and if it detects an element where the scheduled time corresponds with the current time some sort of action (in this case a redirect to add.html is ecpected) should happen. However I don't get any such response...

Like always, I appreciate every kind of solution or help!

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing datetimes the wrong way and that is why your if condition is failing  (Aufgabenzettel.Geplant == now) .
Try comparing them like this:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime
In [2]: past = datetime.now()
In [3]: present = datetime.now()
In [4]: present.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') == past.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S')
Out[17]: False
In [5]: present.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') == past.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
Out[2]: True
```

Usually datetimes are compared after converting them to iso format. You can also use the function .isoformat() from timezone.

Picked it up from here: [How to compare two Datetime field in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068238/how-to-compare-two-datetime-field-in-django?rq=1)